# NameError: name 'nan' is not defined in Series.apply(pd.eval)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, eval

When using `eval` to convert a list string to list type, it's ok to eval with `nan` in list

```py
# Following two ways are both ok 
#from numpy import nan
nan = float('nan')

lst = '[nan, 1]'
print(eval(lst))
```

But same idea doesn't work with `Series.apply(eval)`

```py
import pandas as pd

from numpy import nan
#nan = float('nan') # here

df = pd.DataFrame({'lst': ['[nan, 1, 3]', '[1, 2, 3]']})
df['lst'] = df['lst'].apply(eval)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/sourcecode/test/so/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    df['lst'] = df['lst'].apply(eval)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4433, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1082, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1137, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

Or with `Series.apply(pd.eval)`

```py
import pandas as pd

from numpy import nan
#nan = float('nan') # here

df = pd.DataFrame({'lst': ['[nan, 1, 3]', '[1, 2, 3]']})
df['lst'] = df['lst'].apply(pd.eval)
```

```
KeyError: 'nan'
```

Instead, I need to manually pass `globals` or `local_dict` to [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'lst': ['[nan, 1, 3]', '[1, 2, 3]']})
df['lst1'] = df['lst'].apply(lambda x: pd.eval(x, local_dict={'nan': np.nan}))
df['lst2'] = df['lst'].apply(lambda x: eval(x, {'nan': np.nan}))
```

However, according to the document of [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

> If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed with the *globals* and *locals* in the environment where `eval` is called.

and [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

> `local_dict`: dict or None, optional
>
> A dictionary of local variables, taken from `locals()` by default.
>
> `global_dict`: dict or None, optional
>
> A dictionary of global variables, taken from `globals()` by default.

`local_dict` is taken from `locals()`, in the above `Series.apply(pd.eval)`, when we print the result of `locals()` or `globals()`, we can see `nan` is already defined but why the NameError still occurs?

```py
import pandas as pd

from numpy import nan
#nan = float('nan') # here

print(locals())
print(globals())

df = pd.DataFrame({'lst': ['[nan, 1, 3]', '[1, 2, 3]']})
df['lst'] = df['lst'].apply(pd.eval)
```

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7ffb9e1754e0>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/home/winy/sourcecode/test/so/test.py', '__cached__': None, 'pd': <module 'pandas' from '/home/winy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>, 'nan': nan, 'df':            lst
0  [nan, 1, 3]
1    [1, 2, 3]}
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7ffb9e1754e0>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/home/winy/sourcecode/test/so/test.py', '__cached__': None, 'pd': <module 'pandas' from '/home/winy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>, 'nan': nan, 'df':            lst
0  [nan, 1, 3]
1    [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First argument of [Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) should be function which will be applied to Series value in [Pandas code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.2/pandas/core/series.py#L4433).

When using `df['lst'].apply(pd.eval)`, `pd.eval` is actually called in `pandas.core.series.Series.apply`. The `globals()` then will be that of the `pandas.core.series` module.

However, when using `df['lst'].apply(lambda x: pd.eval(x))`, the `apply` method calls a `lambda` function which is defined in current file and in turn calls `pd.eval`. The `globals()` will be those of the module in which the `lambda` function is defined (i.e. current file).

As a result, if you write the lambda function, you won't see the NameError. In lambda function, `globals()` contains the definition of `nan`

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan


df = pd.DataFrame({'lst': ['[nan, 1, 3]', '[1, 2, 3]']})


df['lst'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
df['lst'].apply(lambda x: pd.eval(x))
```